# Unauthorized Access - mapbox: the server responded with a status of 401

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to follow the leaflet maps tutorial (using Mapbox tiles) in order to basically show a map in my webpage. I made sure to create a personal token and replace it in the tileLayer as it's been recommended. But I always get the 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)' Error in the console.

My code is basically the same as in the tutorial, except I added the generated token:

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
     
</head>
<body>

 <div id="mapid"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onload = loadMap();

function loadMap() {

  var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);


  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={sk.eyJ1IjoiaXFhcmNobGkiLCJhIjoiY2pqZTN1OTNxMGNubDNwbXNhbDNka2J4ZiJ9.UKoT12YRTSSUEnIGHyiScQ}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox-outdoors',
    accessToken: 'sk.eyJ1IjoiaXFhcmNobGkiLCJhIjoiY2pqZTN1OTNxMGNubDNwbXNhbDNka2J4ZiJ9.UKoT12YRTSSUEnIGHyiScQ'
  }).addTo(map);

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting the token in the URL. The `acces_token={accessToken}` will be replaced when the javascript loads. You only need to specify your key like you have here:

`accessToken:'*cut key away*'`

Therefore this should work:

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox-outdoors',
    accessToken: 'sk.eyJ1IjoiaXFhcmNobGkiLCJhIjoiY2pqZTN1OTNxMGNubDNwbXNhbDNka2J4ZiJ9.UKoT12YRTSSUEnIGHyiScQ'
  }).addTo(map);
```